# Why does the triangle inequality not work here?

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima-minima, triangle-inequality

**Question:**

> If $\left|z-i\right|\le2$  and $z_{1}=5+3i$, then find the maximum value of $\left|iz+z_{1}\right|$

**My Approach:**

> $\left|iz+z_{1}\right|\le\left|iz\right|+\left|z_{1}\right|$.
>
> We have, $\left|iz\right|=\left|i\right|\cdot\left|z\right|=\left|z\right|$ and $\left|z_{1}\right|=\sqrt{5^{2}+3^{2}}=\sqrt{34}$
>
> Thus, $\left|iz+z_{1}\right|_{max}=\sqrt{34}+\left|z\right|_{max}=\sqrt{34}+3$

($\left|z\right|_{max}=3$, I got this using the graph of  $\left|z-i\right|\le2$)

But this is not the answer, the answer given is $7$. I think I'm getting the wrong answer because of the restriction $\left|z-i\right|\le2$ on $z$, but I'm not able to proceed. Please help.

Comment: In order for that to be the maximum, it must be possible that $iz$ can be a positive multiple of $5+3i$ under these constraints. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake; it can be a positive multiple of $5+3i$ but if it is then it has modulus considerably less than $3$.

Comment: Surprisingly, Ian's strategy does not work as can be seen through this [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ql2tzj9vg7) visualisation. The answer given appears to be correct however.

Comment: So if the answer is correct, your claim that $|iz+z_1| \leq \sqrt{34} + 3$ is true, but there is no $z$ where that inequality is an equality. You proved a bound, but not the exact maximum.

Comment: Solve this problem geometrically.  Plot $|z-i| \le 2$ on the complex plane (it is a circle centered at i) and $|i(z-iz_0)|$ will be a the distance from a point on this disk to the point $iz_0$

Comment: You have shown that $\sqrt{34} + 3$ is an *upper bound* of $|iz+z_1|$ but not that it is an achieved one, nor even a potential least upper bound.  As $7 \le \sqrt{34} + 3$ you have no contradiction.  (If you had $7 > \sqrt{34} +3$ then something must have gone wrong.)

Comment: @TobyMak A refinement of my strategy works, but it reveals a *competition* between the angle between $iz$ and $z_1$ and the maximum permitted modulus of $iz$ when the angle has that value. The "best" point in the disk balances having a good angle with having a large modulus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you solved it the triangle inequality still holds.  That is it is true that $\sqrt {34} + 3 \ge 7$ but you are not using all of the information most efficiently.

I would suggest you work this out geometrically.  Being able to make these sketches will develop your intuition.

$|z-i|\le 2$ is a disk centered at $i.$

Then you have to work out the distance from  $iz_0$ to the farthest point on the disc.

But here is the algebraic method.

$|iz + 5 + 3i| = |i(z-i) + 4 + 3i| \le |(z-i)| + |4+3i| = 2 + 5$

Comment: Specifically you have equality in the inequality when $i(z-i)$ is a positive multiple of $4+3i$, which is indeed possible here.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The disk $|z - i| ≤ 2$ can be represented as $x^2 + (y - 1)^2 ≤ 4$. Now we can apply the transformation $z \mapsto iz + z_1$ on this disk.

First, multiplying by $i$ results in a counterclockwise rotation of $\pi/2$ around the origin. Using the fact that $\frac{y}{x} \frac{-x}{y} = -1$ to be perpendicular, $(x, y)$ rotated by $\pi/2$ gives $(-y, x)$, which has the same distance as $(x,y)$ to the origin. Thus applying the transformation $x \mapsto -(-y), y \mapsto -(x)$ to the circle, we obtain the equation of the rotated circle $(y)^2 + (-x - 1)^2 = (x +1)^2 + y^2 = 4$.

The translation $iz \mapsto iz + z_1$ is straightforward. Translating the rotated circle by $5 \choose 3$ units gives $(x - 4)^2 + (y - 3)^2 = 4$.

And now, the modulus represents the distance to the origin. The maximum distance occurs when the component in the direction ${4 \choose 3}$, the centre, is maximised. Since the modulus of $4 + 3i$ is $5$, we can achieve a maximum of $2$ units in this direction.

Hence the maximum value of $|iz + z_1|$ is $5 + 2 = \boxed{7}$.